# How to restore for all documents in a library to one version older? Maybe powershell?

Tags: document-library, versioning

I am using sp 2010. I have a document library. I would like to go to one previous version of all the documents in this document library. Maybe in powershell? Something like a foreach loop and for each document go to the previous version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://sp2010
$list = $web.Lists["Documents"]
$items = $list.Items
foreach ($item in $items)
{
    $file = $item.File
    $fileVersions = $file.Versions      
    if ($fileVersions.Count -gt 0)
    {           
        $fileVersions.Restore($fileVersions.Count - 1)          
    }   
}
```

**UPDATE**

Please note that when any of previous versions is restored a new version is created.

Comment: Great! I will try it and let you knwo if it is working

Comment: this script is not working. It creates a new version, but dont changes any metadata. What to do now?

Comment: Try removing check in and check out code statements

Comment: I would like to go from version 0.2 to 0.1. That is not possible with your script because there is a check : if version is greater then 1

Comment: Enhance it to include minor versions

Comment: Nadeem, thanks for your answer, but could you please explain more? Do I need to add something to the script or something else?

Comment: I am on mobile and hence not able to test. Please update the question with full requirements and I can give it a try next working day.

Comment: What do you mean with "Enhance it to include minor versions" ?

Comment: See my updated answer. I have updated the logic in loop and also provided the update. You can confirm from UI that when any previous version is restored a new version is created.

Comment: Thats not the issue Nadeem. I dont have a problem with the new version after I restore to an old version. I dont see the metadata is changed to the previous minor version! This script is only working with major versions.

Comment: Ok, sorry you need to remove the checkout and checkin code. I have updated the code. Try now

Comment: thanks now it works fine without checkin and checkout. I was needed to turn of the required check out option.

Comment: I just wanted to say I recently used this on SharePoint 2016, and this worked perfectly. Thank you once again!